# Accessing various databases as one in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-security

I have two different databases in SQL Server, lets say db1 and db2, and I need to join data between them, but using my application that has access only to db1.

So, I thought of two possibilities: the first one is to create a view in db 1 that reads data from db 2. The second one is to create some kind of logical or virtual database, kind of db3, so I can access db1 and db2 through db3. Is it possible?

Opened for other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is a good option, I don't see the need for a "virtual" db.
 Use the KISS principle.

Comment: I like the view option. My only concern is that the database name in the view to access db2 need to be fixed. As I work for a SW house, database names changes between some customers and in this case we're forced to manualy change the views. Unless there's a trick I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

"logical or virtual database"?
no need. Assuming the DBs are on the same server, a view or even a direct select like select * from db2.dbo.table would do the trick

If they are not, you would need to create a linked server on DB1 pointing to DB2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a stored procedure and do a "union/join" SQL query.

In the SQL Query in the "from" clause you need to write the "from [DatabaseName].[Schema].[Table]"

You need to host the stored procedure in the database where your application has access to.